# Understanding Signals, LTIs and Electrical Circuits

Tags: circuit-design, signal, control

I am an Electrical Engineering student; and recently read through subjects like "*Signals and System*" and "*Control Theory*". The flow on concepts amidst these two subjects was immaculate. I understood that there are some *Linear Time-Invariant Systems* which are made causal and at initial rest for physical purposes. We analyze different singularity and sinusoidal signals through them to reveal their nature via their responses. so on, so forth.

Earlier, I read about "*Electrical Circuits*". I could sense many correlation between these three subjects but I just could not consolidate my understanding. It feels that the circuit theory is an instance of applied physics and this systems theory above. I facing many conceptual lacunae.

If the correlations could be pointed out in an answer or refer me to some relevant resources, I would be glad. The popular texts (Oppenheim, Kuo, Sadiku, Kimmerly, Hayt) have introduced these two domains as divorced as possible. I am dissatisfied by them.

Edit: To be specially specific, I need need some reading resources or answers highlighting connection between LTIs and Circuits.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MiNiMe I added some clarification. Although, I'll admit I don't clearly know what to expect.

Comment: Update: Valkenburg's "Network Analysis" and Guillemin's "Introductory Circuit Theory" is the closer match to what I needed. They are a bit more mathematically expressive in their exposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All electrical circuits made from LTI components are LTI systems. This is handy, as many components like fixed resistors, capacitors, inductors are, or are approximately, linear and time invariant. Other components like diodes or transistors can often be used within a very narrow range of parameters when they can be usefully approximated as linear.

To understand the relation between the areas you are looking at, it's best to do a few numerical exercises solving LTI electrical systems, until you absorb the relationship as natural.

Comment: I understand that various electrical devices have been modelled as linear to flesh out the LTI nature of the entire system. We have extensive theory on LTI system analysis that transfers well to the circuit theory. But how? like how does stability analysis of control theory port to circuit? are circuit diagram/schematics an instance of block diagrams too? we have two state variables - current and voltage, do we draw a state space upon them? How different is circuit analysis from LTI system analysis then? Feedback and superposition; is it engendered by EM physics or LTI system math?

Comment: I believe I have my answers to these trivial questions; I need some sort of validation. If I could get it in some text material, it would have been great. 
LTI theory is introduced as a theory in itself and not in conjunction with electrical circuits. Just as there are engineering texts on EM physics. Some LTI on circuit text could fill in the gaps. Or else I'll just contemplate more on it and give it some time. (^_^)